# Rails search - multiple specific model attributes selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search

I have a database of 'events' with a bunch of attributes. How can I allow my users to search for 'events'. I have seen the tutorial on doing text searches, but I'm looking for more ON/OFF searches.

Each event has a time, location (coordinates), and a few other selectors. I would like a user to be able to search based on time (min,max) and/or location (closest to their input coordinates) and select from selectors.

How can I do this? Any specific tutorials that I should look at. I couldn't find anything near by nears. Thanks

Must include multiple attributes and boolean math (is the search location within 5km of an 'event' location.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/berk/will_filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes). Create a scope for each searchable attribute in a model.
 
For example time attribute:
`scope :time_search, ->(min, max) { where("time_column > ? AND time_column < ?", min, max) }`
And then from controller: `Model.time_search(params[:min], params[:max])`.
You can also chain scopes, like this: `Model.scope_1(param).scope_2(param)`, which will filter records based on criteria from those 2 scopes.

Comment: "Model.scope_1(param).scope_2(param) does than mean I should change your code to "scope_1 :time_search" and my location search should be "scope_2 :location_search"?

Comment: Nope. `scope` is a rails method for defining new scopes (you shouldn't  change it). The name of the scope is a symbol and is defined like this: `scope :your_scope_name_here`.