# Rails withdraw_event_path 'undefined local method'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, path

I found a great solution to a problem of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069923/rails-search-multiple-specific-model-attributes-selector/21070097?noredirect=1#comment31687245_21070097)

I've built it into my own project, but I can't seem to call the withdraw event.

show.html.erb

```
<p><strong>Attendees: </strong>
<ul>
    <% for attendee in @event.users %>
        <% if attendee.id == current_user.id %>
            <li><strong><%= attendee.name %></strong>
                <%= link_to 'Withdraw From Event', withdraw_event_path(@event.id), :method => :post, :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
            </li>
        <% else %>
            <li><%= attendee.username %></li>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>   
</ul>
</p>

<p>
  <%= link_to 'Attend Event', attend_event_path(@event.id), :method => :post %>
</p>
```

event_controller.rb

```
def attend
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  current_user.events << @event
  redirect_to @event, notice: 'You are now attending this event'
end

def withdraw
  event    = Event.find(params[:id])
  attendee = Attendee.find_by_user_id_and_event_id(current_user.id, event.id)

  if attendee.blank?
    redirect_to event
  end
  attendee.delete
  redirect_to event, notice: 'You are no longer attending this event.'
end
```

when I call event->show I get this error

```
undefined local variable or method `withdraw_event_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd5d575a910>:0x007fd5d22a72e0>
```

Any ideas why the path isn't working? I'm new to rails

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `withdraw` to your routes, that will create the method `withdraw_event_path`

```
resources :events do
  member do 
    post 'withdraw'
  end
end
```